# detect assert(0) using tcl/expect

Tags: tcl, expect, assert

Here is my `test.cpp` program.  It exits abnormally via an `assert(0)`.

```
#include <cassert>

int main() {
  assert(0);
}
```

When I run this program directly I get the expected output including a non-zero exit status:

```
$ ./test
...
$ echo $?
134
```

But when I try to detect the abnormal exit in `tcl/expect` I don't seem to be able to:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./test
expect eof
lassign [wait] pid spawnid os_error_flag value

if {$os_error_flag != 0} {
  puts "OS error"
  exit 1
}
if {$value != 0} {
  puts "Application error"
  exit 1
}

puts "No error"
```

When I run that script:

```
$ ./test.expect
No error
```

If I use `exit(1)` instead of `assert(0)` then the tcl script is able to detect the abnormal exit.  Why doesn't `tcl/expect` provide an `OS-` or `application-returned` error code for assertion failures and how can I uniformly detect all abnormal program exits by checking the exit code?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an extended comment:

Running that code, I see:

```
$ ./a.out; echo $?
Assertion failed: (0), function main, file x.c, line 4.
Abort trap: 6
134
```

And in expect, I see:

```
$ expect
expect1.1> spawn ./a.out
spawn ./a.out
47429
expect1.2> expect eof
Assertion failed: (0), function main, file x.c, line 4.
expect1.3> wait
47429 exp6 0 0 CHILDKILLED SIGABRT SIGABRT
```

Looks like you need to look at the elements returned by `wait` beyond the 4th.

Answer (score 0):

When I look up [what `wait` does](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), I see that:

> Additional elements may appear at the end of the return value from **wait**. An optional fifth element identifies a class of information. Currently, the only possible value for this element is CHILDKILLED in which case the next two values are the C-style signal name and a short textual description.

The `assert()` call uses `abort()` to terminate the process if the assertion fails, and that shows up as an exit via SIGABRT.

```
set result [wait]
if {[lindex $result 4] eq "CHILDKILLED"} {
    if {[lindex $result 5] eq "SIGABRT"} {
        # assertion failed, or other abort
    } else {
        # other signal
    } 
} else {
    # normal exit, may be with conventional error
}
```

Error handling can definitely be fiddly!